# Why is jQuery Ajax not processing properly?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need assistance in regard to jQuery Ajax. I'm new to all this so I'm probably making a very trivial mistake, however it's one that I can't seem to figure out. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Please see details below.

Here is the form.

**Form**

```
<form action="scripts/feedback-form.php" method="post" id="feedback-form" name="feedback-form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label for="name">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 form-group">
        <label for="feedback">Feedback</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" name="feedback" id="feedback" placeholder="Enter Feedback" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 btn-wrapper">
        <div class="g-recaptcha feedback-captcha" data-sitekey="-- Site Key Omitted--"></div>
        <div id="feedback-success">
            <p>Thank you for submitting your feedback!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="feedback-error">
            <p>Please fill out required fields.</p>
        </div>  
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary submit" id="submit-feedback" name="submit-feedback" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the Ajax.

**Ajax**

```
$("form[id='feedback-form']").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();        

var $form = $(this),
    $action = $form.attr("action"),
    $method = $form.attr("method"),
    $formData = $form.serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: $action,
    type: $method,
    data: $formData,
    success: function(){
        $(".feedback-captcha").addClass("hidden");
        $("#feedback-success").slideDown(500);
    },
    fail: function(){
        $("#feedback-error").slideDown(500);                
    }
})
.done(function() {
    $("#name").val('');
    $("#email").val('');
    $("#zip").val('');
    $("#feedback").val('');
});
return false;
});
```

Here is the initial Captcha validation which then includes the Config file.

**feedback-form.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit-feedback'])){
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
    $privatekey = "--Private Key Omitted--";
    $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $data = json_decode($response);

    if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){

        //Insert code for True result
        include ("feedback-form-config.php");

    }
}
?>
```

Here is the simple PHP file that is supposed to process the email the form contents.

**PHP Config File**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$to = 'someone@somewhere.com';
$subject = 'Project Form';
$message = 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
$message .= 'You received this message because ' . $_POST['name'] . ' requested to be added to the information mailing list.' . "\r\n";
$message .= 'Zip: ' . $_POST['zip'] . "\r\n";
$message .= 'Feedback ' . $_POST['feedback'] . "\r\n";
$message .= 'Regards,' . "\r\n";
$message .= 'System Administrator';
$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: ' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not processing properly"? What is happening? What is being logged?

Comment: And the problem is? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: After filling out the form and pressing the Submit button it appears that Ajax runs since the "Success" function runs and displays the appropriate message, but the Captcha does not receive "class=hidden". 

`success: function(){
        $(".feedback-captcha").addClass("hidden");
        $("#feedback-success").slideDown(500);
    }`

However all the fields are cleared as expected but highlight red as if they haven't been filled out. On top of this there is no email that is sent.

Comment: Please see URL to view actual page.

http://mbimedia.com/uploads/evspip-test-website/